# Unable to remove whitespaces from list items

Tags: python, python-3.x

Would request you to help me out on this , I am unable to remove white spaces from list elements which show unnecessary whitespaces . Can you please help me remove it .

I need to fetch lines having ip 1.1.1.1/32 and 3.3.3.3/32 in the beginning and fetch all the items in a list.

I tried the same through regex, the white spaces are removed but i am unable to fetch the last digit item from table .

Please provide the solution for the same :

```
import re
from io import StringIO

output = """
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  |           Up              |         Down              |
  Net     Prefix  |---------------------------+---------------------------
                  |       ASR        |  L     |       A          | Label  |
------------------+------------------+--------+------------------+---------
        1.1.1.1/32|  162.148.102.2:0 |     102|         -        |    -   |
     10.10.40.0/24|  162.148.102.2:0 |     101|         -        |    -   |
        1.1.1.1/32|  162.148.102.2:0 |     100|         -        |    -   |
        3.3.3.3/32|         -        |    -   |  162.148.102.2:0 |     103|
  192.158.104.0/24|         -        |    -   |  162.148.102.2:0 |     105|
        2.2.2.2/32|         -        |    -   |  162.148.102.2:0 |     106|
     10.30.50.0/24|         -        |    -   |  162.148.102.2:0 |     107|

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""



a = "1.1.1.1/32"
b = "3.3.3.3/32"
output  = StringIO (output)

i = 0
j = 0
for line in output.read().split('\n'):
    if b in line:
        tempa_i = line.strip().split('|')
        res_i = [ele for ele in tempa_i if ele.strip(' ')]
        i = i+1
    if a in line:
        tempb_j = re.findall(r'(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})',line)
        j = j+1

print (i)
print (j)

for list_ in range (i):
    print((res_i))
for list_ in range (j):
    print(tempb_j)
```

Observed Output :

```
['3.3.3.3/32', '         -        ', '    -   ', '  162.148.102.2:0 ', '     103']
['1.1.1.1', '162.148.102.2']
['1.1.1.1', '162.148.102.2']
```

Expected output:

```
['3.3.3.3/32', '-', '-', '162.148.102.2:0', '103']
['1.1.1.1/32', '162.148.102.2:0', '102', '-', '-']
['1.1.1.1/32', '162.148.102.2:0', '100', '-', '-']
```

Comment: Maybe you should start with posting the code which can print something, and not just crash.

Comment: You just edited the code, which was crashing before.

Comment: wow , you did noticed it finally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension, and the `str.strip()` method to remove all the white-spaces on the sides of all the strings in the list:

```
lst = [...]
lst = [s.strip() for s in lst]
```

---

---

If you want to remove *all* the white-spaces in the strings, not just on the sides, you can use `str.replace()`:

```
lst = [...]
lst = [s.replace(' ','') for s in lst]
```

Comment: thanks madme , kudos to you and great answer in single shot

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution, you can order the list to your preference.
Note: Only python 2.

```
from io import StringIO

output = """
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  |           Up              |         Down              |
  Net     Prefix  |---------------------------+---------------------------
                  |       ASR        |  L     |       A          | Label  |
------------------+------------------+--------+------------------+---------
        1.1.1.1/32|  162.148.102.2:0 |     102|         -        |    -   |
     10.10.40.0/24|  162.148.102.2:0 |     101|         -        |    -   |
        1.1.1.1/32|  162.148.102.2:0 |     100|         -        |    -   |
        3.3.3.3/32|         -        |    -   |  162.148.102.2:0 |     103|
  192.158.104.0/24|         -        |    -   |  162.148.102.2:0 |     105|
        2.2.2.2/32|         -        |    -   |  162.148.102.2:0 |     106|
     10.30.50.0/24|         -        |    -   |  162.148.102.2:0 |     107|

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""



a = "1.1.1.1/32"
b = "3.3.3.3/32"
output  = StringIO(output.decode('utf-8'))

for line in output.read().split('\n'):
    if b in line:
      items = line.encode('utf-8').split('|')
      tempa_i = [i.strip() for i in items if i]
      print(tempa_i)

    if a in line:
      items = line.encode('utf-8').split('|')
      tempa_j = [i.strip() for i in items if i]
      print(tempa_j)


# THIS PRINTS:

# ['1.1.1.1/32', '162.148.102.2:0', '102', '-', '-']
# ['1.1.1.1/32', '162.148.102.2:0', '100', '-', '-']
# ['3.3.3.3/32', '-', '-', '162.148.102.2:0', '103']
```

Comment: Just a tip mate: “I guess it should work” won’t fly in the real world.  **Always test.** Because I can assure you just by looking at the code that this **will not** work in Py3.

Comment: Yes your are right, my mistake, this works only for python 2

Comment: Thank you for addressing.  May I recommend upgrading to Py3 as Py2 is no longer supported as of 1 Jan 2020.  Besides, Py3 has some great/easier features!

Comment: Yes I being reading about it, will be updating very soon, thank you very much for the advice !